# How to make "Go to Folder" show current path?

Tags: terminal, finder, path

One thing about MacOS I don't understand is how to quickly navigate the Finder in terms of quickly editing your file path.

I.e in a centralised Version Control I may have

```
/Software Projects/My Project/Branch1/Solution/Models/
```

and I want to get to

```
/Software Projects/My Project/Branch2/Solution/Models/
```

In Windows, I would just quickly go to the file path and swap the 1 for a 2, but in Mac "Go To Folder" always retains the last folder I used, and it appears I either have to type the whole path out, or open a second Finder window, "Go to Folder", drag the folder from my first window in and *then* swap the 1 for a 2.

There MUST be a way for "Go to folder" to just load the current working directory...but I can't seem to find a way anywhere!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A pretty quick solution in Sierra:

- Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + right click on item -> copy "foo" as path name
- Then press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and paste your copied path with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
- Edit your pasted path and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>